# License condition of files ending with .css or .html in material design lite-Framework-1.2.0

Tags: material-design-lite

I was going through the license condition of Material Design Lite- Framework-1.2.0. All of the source files are licensed under Apache V2.0 License but 'LICENSE' file has following infomation "All code in any directories or sub-directories that end with *.html or *.css is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution International    4.0 License, which full text can be found here:    https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/legalcode .". I would like to know whether the files ending with .css or .html are licensed under Apache V2.0 license or Creative Commons Attribution International 4.0 License?